# Maximum value of $|Z_1-Z_2|^2 +|Z_2-Z_3|^2+|Z_3-Z_1|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given three complex numbers $|Z_1|= 2 , |Z_2|= 3, |Z_3| = 4$ find the maximum value of $$|Z_1-Z_2|^2 +|Z_2-Z_3|^2+|Z_3-Z_1|^2$$

If we treat them as three vectors $a, b, c$ centred at zero the above expression becomes $$2(|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2)-2(a\cdot b + b\cdot c + c\cdot a)$$
I've been unsuccessful trying to find the minimum value of $a\cdot b + b\cdot c + c\cdot a$.

Comment: There probably do exist some more elegant ways to do it with some clever use of inequalities, but in general this can be solved using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: You're correct with your approach, more on that, it can be written as $3(|a|² + |b|² + |c|²) - (a + b + c)²$ and since there vectors are always linearly independent in a plane, the second term is zero. I had posted it in chat, don't know if you saw.